# Populate two object items on a single UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

Im new to IOS development, I get an object array from the server and i need to populate two object items per row, on a single UITableViewCell. Whats the best way to do this without using a UICollectionView inside the UITableViewCell?

Comment: think this question is a good candidate to be down voted https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use `UIStackView` or just manually insert your cloned views one by one, adjusting correct frames. What's the problem here?

Comment: Vadim cant u please post the answer with a code snippet with the delegate methods sir

Comment: @DanuthaFernando please show some data you are receiving from server and the code what you have tried so far.

Comment: @DanuthaFernando, pls show us what have you done so far.

Comment: Could you please add your code

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use a custom tableview cell. You can create a view xib and source file, register it via the ViewDidLoad method, then call on the custom cell in the "cellForRow" method. I think that this is the easiest approach for beginners as there are loads of tutorials out there for these things.

Comment: I have a custom TableViewCell but my question is how can I two objects per Cell

Comment: Can you be more specific on what these objects are?

Comment: array objects as I have mentioned in the question

Comment: array objects are not UI components, my man. You have to say, something like: "I want to use two objects, which are arrays, and they will hold an array of UIButtons".